# Comparing single dataframe value to previous 10 in same column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, dataframe, vectorization

In a dataframe, I would like to count how many of the prices from the previous 10 days are greater than today's price. Result would look like this:

```
price   ct>prev10
50.00   
51.00   
52.00   
50.50   
51.00   
50.00   
50.50   
53.00   
52.00   
49.00   
51.00   3
```

I have seen this post answered by DSM, but the requirement was different in that the base for comparison was a static number as opposed to  the current row:

[Achieving "countif" with pd.rolling_sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506255/in-pandas-how-to-calculate-countif-on-a-moving-window-basis)

Of course I would like to do this without looping through 1x1. Pretty much stumped - thanks in advance for any advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `rolling_apply` function on the series.  I used a window length of 5 given the small size of the sample data, but you can easily change it.

The `lambda` function counts the number of items in the rolling group (excluding the last item) is greater than the last item.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [50, 51, 52, 50.5, 51, 50, 50.5, 53, 52, 49, 51]})

window = 5  # Given that sample data only contains 11 values.
df['price_count'] = pd.rolling_apply(df.price, window, 
                                     lambda group: sum(group[:-1] > group[-1]))
>>> df
    price  price_count
0    50.0          NaN
1    51.0          NaN
2    52.0          NaN
3    50.5          NaN
4    51.0            1
5    50.0            4
6    50.5            2
7    53.0            0
8    52.0            1
9    49.0            4
10   51.0            2
```

In the example above, the first group is the prices with index values 0-4.  You can see what is happening with:

```
group = df.price[:window].values
>>> group
array([ 50. ,  51. ,  52. ,  50.5,  51. ])
```

Now, do your comparison of the previous four prices to the current price:

```
>>> group[:-1] > group[-1]
array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Then, you are just summing the boolean values:

```
>>> sum(group[:-1] > group[-1])
1
```

This is the value that gets put into the first closing window at index 4.

Comment: hi Alexander, ty for your fast response. I believe this is exactly what I need, but I don't completely understand it yet. If I would like to have the lookback period be 5 days NOT including today, how would I adjust what you wrote? I know I can make window=6, but just to better understand your solution, would it be:  pd.rolling_apply(df.price, window, lambda group: sum(group[:-1] > group[-2])) ?

Comment: The last day of the window is excluded from the comparison.  See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectoized approach with [`NumPy`](http://www.numpy.org/) module that supports [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for implementing vectorized methods -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample input dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [50, 51, 52, 50.5, 51, 50, 50.5, 53, 52, 49, 51]})

# Convert to numpy array for counting purposes
A = np.array(df['price'])

W = 5 # Window size

# Initialize another column for storing counts
df['price_count'] = np.nan

# Get counts and store as a new column in dataframe
C = (A[np.arange(A.size-W+1)[:,None] + np.arange(W-1)] > A[W-1:][:,None]).sum(1)
df['price_count'][W-1:] = C
```

Sample run -

```
>>> df
    price
0    50.0
1    51.0
2    52.0
3    50.5
4    51.0
5    50.0
6    50.5
7    53.0
8    52.0
9    49.0
10   51.0
>>> A = np.array(df['price'])
>>> W = 5 # Window size
>>> df['price_count'] = np.nan
>>> 
>>> C=(A[np.arange(A.size-W+1)[:,None] + np.arange(W-1)] > A[W-1:][:,None]).sum(1)
>>> df['price_count'][W-1:] = C
>>> df
    price  price_count
0    50.0          NaN
1    51.0          NaN
2    52.0          NaN
3    50.5          NaN
4    51.0            1
5    50.0            4
6    50.5            2
7    53.0            0
8    52.0            1
9    49.0            4
10   51.0            2
```