# python pandas- AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'?

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions, series

I am trying to count the number of times the current row's value for a specific column 'df1' falls between the low-high range values in the previous 5 rows (in 2 side by side columns). This is a follow-up question - Dickster has already done the heavy lifting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271809/how-can-i-replicate-excel-countifs-in-python-pandas).

The Series().between() method is not cooperating, complaining that `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`. I don't understand how I am involving the `columns` attribute.

```
list1 = [[21,101],[22,110],[25,113],[24,112],[21,109],[28,108],[30,102],[26,106],[25,111],[24,110]]
dict1 = {}
dict1['df1'] = pd.DataFrame(list1,index=pd.date_range('2000-1-1',periods=10, freq='D'), columns=list('AB'))
dict1['df2'] = pd.DataFrame(dict1['df1'] * (1-.05))
pan_so = pd.Panel(dict1)
pan_so = pan_so.transpose(2,1,0)

x = pan_so.ix[0,:,:]
def btwn(x):  # x is a dataframe
    y = x['df1'].rolling(center=False,window=6)
    z = x['df2'].rolling(center=False,window=6)
    x['cnt_btwn'] = pd.Series(pd.Series(y[:-1]).between(z[-1], y[-1], inclusive=True).sum())
    return x
btwn(x)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `y[:-1]` makes an access to a `Rolling` object that doesn't support column indexing, that is the meaning of `[:-1]` in your code. You should apply a transformation function and get an actual series before filtering.

Comment: Hi Boud - Possible to be a little more specific on the transformation function?

Comment: like mean max count etc. it s unclear to me why you put such [:-1] there and the previous question is heavy to read; what I do know though is that y is a Rolling object here and not a series so you cannot call that on that given location of the instruction

Comment: I want to compare "current" row's data to a rolling window which is [curr-6:curr-1], so the the [:-1] is just isolating the current row. Thank you for putting me on the right path.