# Pandas accidentally setting entire column, not last in row

Tags: python, pandas

This may be a dumb question but I am a tad stuck with this. Say I have this dataframe:

```
   amount  amount_str  buy_order_id        id   midprice       price  
0  0.01545000  0.01545000     915692220  53424450  0.1286495  0.12947460   
0  1.65956203  1.65956203     915692330  53424458        NaN  0.12947460   
0  0.68427900  0.68427900     915692581  53424487        NaN  0.12947460   
0  0.22306417  0.22306417     915692632  53424491        NaN  0.12808629   
0  0.22306396  0.22306396     915692964  53424530        NaN  0.12808646   
0  2.31474046  2.31474046     915693081  53424535        NaN  0.12947460   
0  0.16808924  0.16808924     915694097  53424600        NaN  0.12808675   
0  5.30166589  5.30166589     915694819  53424629        NaN  0.12808710   
price_str  sell_order_id   timestamp  type  
0  0.12947460      915690988  1518045004     0  
0  0.12947460      915690988  1518045006     0  
0  0.12947460      915690988  1518045010     0  
0  0.12808629      915692647  1518045010     1  
0  0.12808646      915693012  1518045016     1  
0  0.12947460      915690988  1518045017     0  
0  0.12808675      915694117  1518045031     1  
0  0.12808710      915694862  1518045041     1
```

Here is my issue: each time the program gets a new order from bitstamp, it appends the values to this dataframe, and then adds the current midprice.

I could normally do that with `df['midprice'] = value`; however, this sets it for the entire column and not just that entry.

How would I make it so it adds it per line and not to the entire column?

Thanks!

Comment: "I could normally do that with `df['midprice'] = value`" this should never work as a method for appending to a dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas specialises in vectorised calculations.

So `df['midprice'] = value` sets an entire series (or column) to a fixed value.

It seems like you want to amend the *last* midprice value only, straight after a row is added by another process. This is one way you can achieve this:

```
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('midprice')] = value
```

Comment: something like this was exactly what I was loking for, let me see if this works. I knew it had to do with one of the  iloc, loc, or iat, at.

Comment: Is this inline btw?

Comment: @xxen0nxx, not sure what you mean by inline

Comment: hmm, im getting an error. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: convention is `df` refers to dataframe. try it with the correct variable.

Comment: can you print `type(df)`?

Comment: sell_order_id   timestamp  type    midprice  
0      915882866  1518047205     0  0.12662148  
   amount  amount_str  buy_order_id        id       price   price_str  \
0     0.5  0.50000000     915882917  53435169  0.12689309  0.12689309

Comment: and the one after is

Comment: 915882866  1518047205     0  0.12662148  
       amount  amount_str  buy_order_id        id    midprice       price  \
0  0.50000000  0.50000000     915882917  53435169  0.12662148  0.12689309   
0  0.61658571  0.61658571     915883324  53435190         NaN  0.12570006   

    price_str  sell_order_id   timestamp  type  
0  0.12689309      915882866  1518047205     0  
0  0.12570006      915884248  1518047221     1

Comment: nope, that's not `type(df)`. if you can't print this, it's hard to help!

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> is the type

Comment: and now what do you get when you print `df.columns`?

Comment: This is what I get.

Comment: Index([       u'amount',    u'amount_str',  u'buy_order_id',            u'id',
            u'midprice',         u'price',     u'price_str', u'sell_order_id',
           u'timestamp',          u'type'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: so your error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'" cannot be correct for the line of code i provided - pls post full error & traceback on your question.

Comment: hmm It wont let me paste it, to large. Here it is on pastebin. https://pastebin.com/cjTgzcXU

Comment: could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366120/python-pandas-attributeerror-series-object-has-no-attribute-columns

Comment: Hmm, weird. What does not make sense to me is why is it saying series object when it is a dataframe. very strange.